# Retrive only records without record associated in another table

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have two tables `Clazzes` and `Teachers`, both are joined by a third Table `clazzes_teachears`. How I can retrive the `Clazzes` that has no `Teachers` associated ? now I can only return all `Clazzes` elements with or without Teacher associated.

**ClazzesTable.php Initialize**

```
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    parent::initialize($config);

    $this->table('clazzes');
    $this->displayField('name');
    $this->primaryKey('id');

    $this->belongsToMany('Teachers', [
        'foreignKey' => 'clazz_id',
        'targetForeignKey' => 'teacher_id',
        'joinTable' => 'clazzes_teachers'
    ]);
}
```

**TeachersTable.php Initialize**

```
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    parent::initialize($config);

    $this->table('teachers');
    $this->displayField('id');
    $this->primaryKey('id');

    $this->belongsToMany('Clazzes', [
        'foreignKey' => 'teacher_id',
        'targetForeignKey' => 'clazze_id',
        'joinTable' => 'clazzes_teachers'
    ]);
}
```

> **Note:** doesn't exist ClazzesTeachersTable.php

Method to return All Clazzes with/without teachers associated (I need retrive only `Clazzes` without `Teachers`)

```
public function getAllClazzesRecursive(){
    return $this
        ->find('all')
        ->contain([
            'Teachers' => function($q) {
                return $q->select(['id', 'registry', 'url_lattes', 'entry_date', 'formation', 'workload', 'about', 'rg', 'cpf', 'birth_date', 'situation']);
            }
        ])->hydrate(false)->toArray();
}
```

**Teacher sql:**

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `teachers` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `registry` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`));
```

**Clazzes sql:**

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `clazzes` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`));
```

**clazzes_teachers sql:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `clazzes_teachers` (
  `clazz_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `teacher_id` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`clazz_id`, `teacher_id`));
```

Comment: I don't know enough about cakephp 3.0 to answer this properly, but I think a `left join clazzes_teachers on clazzes_teachers.clazz_id = clazzes.id` with a where condition `where clazzes_teachers.clazz_id is null`. I could write this up with a cakephp 2.x `find('all', array(...));` if you think that'd help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use join to query builder , see more http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#adding-joins

```
 public function getAllClazzesRecursive(){
    return $this
        ->find('all')
        ->join([
          'table' => 'clazzes_teachers',
          'alias' => 'ct',
          'type' => 'LEFT',
          'conditions' => 'ct.clazz_id= clazzes.id',
         ])
       ->where('ct.id IS NULL')
       ->hydrate(false)->toArray();
}
```

you can also use `leftJoin()` directly.